# Replicate selected estimates

Tags: least-squares

I can't replicate some published results in a textbook despite being given both the underlying data and equation to be estimated. I wondered if anyone on this forum was able to, and if so, how?

In Christopher J. O'Donnell's 2018 textbook entitled "Productivity and efficiency analysis: an economic approach to measuring and explaining managerial performance", he asserts that you can use least squares estimation to generate the results in Table 1 using the small sample data in Table 2 and the following equation:

$\ln q_{1it} = \alpha(t) + \sum_{j=1}^{J} \delta_j \ln z_{jit} + \sum_{m=1}^M\beta_m \ln x_{mit} -\frac{1}{\tau}\ln(\sum_{n=1}^N\gamma_nq_{nit}^{*\tau})-u_{it}$

$\text{where } \alpha(t)\equiv\ln A(t), q_{nit}^*\equiv\frac{q_{nit}}{q_{1it}},\text{ and } u_{it} \text{ is a random variable with the following properties:}$

1. $E(u_{it})=u\geq0 \text{ for all } i \text{ and } t.$
2. $var(u_{it})\propto\sigma_{u}^2\text{ for all } i \text{ and } t.$
3. $cov(u_{it},u_{ks}) = 0 \text{ if } i\ne k \text{ or } t \ne s.$
4. $u_{it} \text{ is uncorrelated with the explanatory variables.}$

#### Table 1: Results

```
╔════════════════╦══════════╗
║   Parameter    ║ Estimate ║
╠════════════════╬══════════╣
║ α(1) ≡ ln A(1) ║ 0.954    ║
║ α(2) ≡ ln A(2) ║ 0.903    ║
║ α(3) ≡ ln A(3) ║ 0.702    ║
║ α(4) ≡ ln A(4) ║ 0.723    ║
║ α(5) ≡ ln A(5) ║ 0.782    ║
║ δ 1            ║ 0.188    ║
║ β 1            ║ 0.093    ║
║ β 2            ║ 0.259    ║
║ γ 1            ║ 0.771    ║
║ γ 2            ║ 0.229    ║
║ τ              ║ −0.083   ║
╚════════════════╩══════════╝
```

#### Table 2: Data

```
╔═════╦══════╦════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══╗
║ Row ║ Firm ║ Period ║  q1   ║  q2   ║  x1   ║  x2   ║ z ║
╠═════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══╣
║ A   ║    1 ║      1 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1 ║
║ B   ║    2 ║      1 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 0.56  ║ 0.56  ║ 1 ║
║ C   ║    3 ║      1 ║ 2.37  ║ 2.37  ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1 ║
║ D   ║    4 ║      1 ║ 2.11  ║ 2.11  ║ 1.05  ║ 0.7   ║ 1 ║
║ E   ║    5 ║      1 ║ 1.81  ║ 3.62  ║ 1.05  ║ 0.7   ║ 1 ║
║ F   ║    1 ║      2 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 0.996 ║ 0.316 ║ 2 ║
║ G   ║    2 ║      2 ║ 1.777 ║ 3.503 ║ 1.472 ║ 0.546 ║ 2 ║
║ H   ║    3 ║      2 ║ 0.96  ║ 0.94  ║ 0.017 ║ 0.346 ║ 1 ║
║ I   ║    4 ║      2 ║ 5.82  ║ 0.001 ║ 4.545 ║ 0.01  ║ 2 ║
║ J   ║    5 ║      2 ║ 6.685 ║ 0.001 ║ 4.45  ║ 0.001 ║ 1 ║
║ K   ║    1 ║      3 ║ 1.381 ║ 4.732 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1 ║
║ L   ║    2 ║      3 ║ 0.566 ║ 4.818 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1 ║
║ M   ║    3 ║      3 ║ 1     ║ 3     ║ 1.354 ║ 1     ║ 1 ║
║ N   ║    4 ║      3 ║ 0.7   ║ 0.7   ║ 0.33  ║ 0.16  ║ 1 ║
║ O   ║    5 ║      3 ║ 2     ║ 2     ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 2 ║
║ P   ║    1 ║      4 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 0.657 ║ 0.479 ║ 1 ║
║ R   ║    2 ║      4 ║ 1     ║ 3     ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1 ║
║ S   ║    3 ║      4 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1.933 ║ 0.283 ║ 2 ║
║ T   ║    4 ║      4 ║ 1.925 ║ 3.722 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 2 ║
║ U   ║    5 ║      4 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 0.31  ║ 1 ║
║ V   ║    1 ║      5 ║ 1     ║ 5.166 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1 ║
║ W   ║    2 ║      5 ║ 2     ║ 2     ║ 0.919 ║ 0.919 ║ 2 ║
║ X   ║    3 ║      5 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 1.464 ║ 0.215 ║ 2 ║
║ Y   ║    4 ║      5 ║ 1     ║ 1     ║ 0.74  ║ 0.74  ║ 1 ║
║ Z   ║    5 ║      5 ║ 1.81  ║ 3.62  ║ 2.1   ║ 1.4   ║ 1 ║
╚═════╩══════╩════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══╝
```

I'm particularly confused by the fact that one of the parameters to be estimated — tau $(\tau$) — is required to transform the explanatory variable $q_{nit}^*$, but is unknown before estimation.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $q_{nit}^*\equiv\frac{q_nit}{q_1it}$ should be $q_{nit}^*\equiv\frac{q_{nit}}{q_{1it}}$?

Comment: Yes, good pick up. That was a transcription error on my part. I've edited this now so "i" and "t" are subscripts in both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tau is just another parameter that needs to be estimated.  The model is nonlinear in the parameters.  The results in Table 1 in this post were obtained using (corrected) nonlinear least squares.  The R code is available at http://extras.springer.com/2018/978-981-13-2982-1.